# How can i use a textBox.Text in backgroundworker without using cross thread?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the line in the dowork event

```
List<string> Result = SearchInFile(CurrentFileWithPath, textBox2.Text);
```

And this is the whole dowork event code

```
object[] CurrentStatus;
        private void _FileProcessingWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int countmore = 0;
            try
            {
                //object[] CurrentStatus = new object[5];
                DirectoryInfo[] MySubDirectories = (DirectoryInfo[])e.Argument;
                for (int i = 0; i < MySubDirectories.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo MySubDirectory = MySubDirectories[i];

                    List<FileInfo> l = new List<FileInfo>();
                    CountFiles(MySubDirectory, l);
                    CurrentStatus = new object[6];
                    int totalFiles = l.Count;
                    CurrentStatus[3] = i.ToString();
                    countmore += totalFiles;
                    CurrentStatus[4] = countmore;
                    _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);

                    string CurrentDirectory = "Current Directory: " + MySubDirectory.Name;

                    foreach (FileInfo MyFile in l)
                    {
                        CurrentStatus = new object[6];
                        if (_FileProcessingWorker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            return;
                        }

                        if (MyFile.Extension.ToLower() == ".cs" || MyFile.Extension.ToLower() == ".vb")
                        {
                            string CurrentFile = "Current File: " + MyFile.Name;
                            string CurrentFileWithPath = MyFile.FullName;

                            CurrentStatus[0] = CurrentDirectory;
                            CurrentStatus[1] = CurrentFile;
                            _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);

                            List<string> Result = SearchInFile(CurrentFileWithPath, textBox2.Text);

                            if (Result != null && Result.Count > 0)
                            {
                                CurrentStatus[2] = Result;
                                _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return;
            }  
        }
```

I'm not getting errors but using a break point I see on the textBox2 text:
Text = The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

If there is no other way how to use cross thread with it ?

Comment: Only if you store the content of textbox2.Text in a member variable or so before _FileProcessingWorker_DoWork is called.

Comment: You should probably do what @Christoph says anyway - what if the user changes the text in the middle of your BackgroundWorker's run?

Comment: You can pass all data to the DoWork event when starting the background worker (you can access it by retrieving the Argument property of the eventargs of your dowork event).

Comment: vesan good question. Now I guess it will change the whole searching string if the user change it in the middle or I could lock the textbox and not allowed to change it while searching in on. Or and this one I don't know how to do but maybe I can save the last searching string in a text file or as settings and when the user change in the middle it will search for multiple texts. What do you think should be the best thing to handle it ?